# When are $\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^c$ and $\frac{a^c}{b^c}$ equivalent?

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

Consider the following two expressions

\begin{equation}
    \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^c
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{a^c}{b^c}
\end{equation}

where $a,b,c$ are complex numbers.

I would like to know for what values of $a,b,c$ are the two expressions equivalent.

One example where they aren't equivalent is $b = c = 0$, then the first expression is undefined and the second expression is $1$. It's also clear that equivalence holds if $b \neq 0$ and $c \in \mathbb{Z}$. Could somebody help me determine the complete set of values where equivalence holds?

P.S. This question is derived from the SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372814/matlab-symbolic).

Comment: $0^0$ is also undefined. What is equal to $1$ is the expression $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = 1$. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%5E0

Comment: @ArsenBerk Oh I didn't know that. So it may be that these two expressions are always equivalent when defined?

Comment: This is really not about equivalence relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to find it out by considering two cases.

**Case 1 ($c \in \mathbb{Z}$):** First, let $a = r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $b = r_2e^{i\theta_2}$. Then we have
$$\bigg(\frac{a}{b}\bigg)^c = \bigg(\frac{r_1e^{i\theta_1}}{r_2e^{i\theta_2}}\bigg)^c = \bigg(\frac{r_1}{r_2}\bigg)^c \cdot e^{i(\theta_1-\theta_2)c} = \frac{r_1^c}{r_2^c}\cdot\frac{e^{i\theta_1c}}{e^{i \theta_2c}} = \frac{a^c}{b^c}$$
so whenever this expression is defined, they are equivalent.

**Case 2 ($c \in \mathbb{C}$):** We will use the fact:

> Let $z,c \in \mathbb{C}$. Then $z^c = e^{c\log(z)}$

We have
$$\frac{a^c}{b^c}= \frac{e^{c \log(a)}}{e^{c \log(b)}} = e^{c(\log(a)-\log(b))} = e^{c \log(\frac{a}{b})} = \bigg(\frac{a}{b}\bigg)^c$$
Therefore they are always equivalent when the expression is defined as you suggested.